# Voldemort issue and error

Tags: java, memcached, voldemort

Today i tried voldemort with my linux machine, but i cant proceed fully. Following error i got it while try to store a value by using "PUT" keyword.

pls look at this information and get the solution

```
server.properties
bdb.sync.transactions=false
bdb.cache.size=1000MB

max.threads=5000

http.enable=true
socket.enable=true

node.id=0
```

kumaran@mohandoss-Vostro-1550:/home/kumaran/voldemort-1.3.0$ ./bin/voldemort-admin-tool.sh --get-metadata --url tcp://localhost:5555

```
[19:05:55,373 voldemort.store.socket.clientrequest.ClientRequestExecutorFactory$ClientRequestSelectorManager] INFO Closed, exiting  [voldemort-niosocket-client-3]
 [19:05:55,374 voldemort.store.socket.clientrequest.ClientRequestExecutorFactory$ClientRequestSelectorManager] INFO Closed, exiting  [voldemort-niosocket-client-8]
 [19:05:55,374 voldemort.store.socket.clientrequest.ClientRequestExecutorFactory$ClientRequestSelectorManager] INFO Closed, exiting  [voldemort-niosocket-client-7]
 [19:05:55,373 voldemort.store.socket.clientrequest.ClientRequestExecutorFactory$ClientRequestSelectorManager] INFO Closed, exiting  [voldemort-niosocket-client-6]
 [19:05:55,373 voldemort.store.socket.clientrequest.ClientRequestExecutorFactory$ClientRequestSelectorManager] INFO Closed, exiting  [voldemort-niosocket-client-5]
 [19:05:55,373 voldemort.store.socket.clientrequest.ClientRequestExecutorFactory$ClientRequestSelectorManager] INFO Closed, exiting  [voldemort-niosocket-client-4]
 [19:05:55,373 voldemort.store.socket.clientrequest.ClientRequestExecutorFactory$ClientRequestSelectorManager] INFO Closed, exiting  [voldemort-niosocket-client-1]
 [19:05:55,373 voldemort.store.socket.clientrequest.ClientRequestExecutorFactory$ClientRequestSelectorManager] INFO Closed, exiting  [voldemort-niosocket-client-2]
 [19:05:55,376 voldemort.store.socket.clientrequest.ClientRequestExecutor] WARN No client associated with Socket[unconnected]  [main]
 [19:05:55,376 voldemort.store.socket.clientrequest.ClientRequestExecutor] INFO Closing remote connection from Socket[unconnected]  [main]
 localhost:0
Key - cluster.xml
version() ts:1379597320733
: <cluster>
  <name>Kumaran</name>
  <server>
    <id>0</id>
    <host>localhost</host>
    <http-port>8081</http-port>
    <socket-port>5554</socket-port>
    <admin-port>5555</admin-port>
    <partitions>0, 1</partitions>
  </server>
  <server>
    <id>1</id>
    <host>localhost</host>
    <http-port>8082</http-port>
    <socket-port>5556</socket-port>
    <admin-port>5557</admin-port>
    <partitions>2, 3</partitions>
  </server>
</cluster>

Key - stores.xml
version() ts:1379597320847
: <stores>
  <store>
    <name>test1</name>
    <persistence>bdb</persistence>
    <routing-strategy>consistent-routing</routing-strategy>
    <routing>client</routing>
    <replication-factor>2</replication-factor>
    <required-reads>2</required-reads>
    <required-writes>2</required-writes>
    <key-serializer>
      <type>string</type>
      <schema-info version="0">UTF-8</schema-info>
    </key-serializer>
    <value-serializer>
      <type>string</type>
      <schema-info version="0">UTF-8</schema-info>
    </value-serializer>
  </store>
</stores>

Key - server.state
version() ts:1379597320870
: NORMAL_SERVER

Key - node.id
version() ts:1379597320865
: 0

Key - rebalancing.steal.info.key
version() ts:1379597320869
: []

localhost:1
Key - cluster.xml
Error in retrieving Failure while checking out socket for localhost:5557(ad1):

Key - stores.xml
Error in retrieving Failure while checking out socket for localhost:5557(ad1):

Key - server.state
Error in retrieving Failure while checking out socket for localhost:5557(ad1):

Key - node.id
Error in retrieving Failure while checking out socket for localhost:5557(ad1):

Key - rebalancing.steal.info.key
Error in retrieving Failure while checking out socket for localhost:5557(ad1):
```

- Kumaran

Answer (score 0):

Unreachable store exception, try caching your client connection, probably got too many open connections and are now being refused.

Make sure you have enough client side threads to handle your server connection threads.

Can't give much more help as your question is not exactly detailed or helpful.